# What are some good pages to redirect users to if they are using an old browser?

Tags: browsers, browser-support

Such as this one: http://www.webstandards.org/upgrade except it's just awful and is way out of date (use Netscape 7? really?)

I am going to require IE9+ and the latest versions of the rest of the browsers.

Thanks.

Comment: a site may not look the same in IE6 but IE6 users don't know the difference. I write tons of front end javascript and there are lots of methods and shims to help support new features in older browsers. Your idea just creates a poor user experience

Comment: @charlietfl my idea creates an excellent user experience for 98% of users in my case. I'm pretty happy with that.

Comment: certainly depends on the type of site. Most business sites can't ignore older browsers. IE < 9 is still very common. You certainly don't want to redirect people away from your site, that's just bad practice

Comment: take a look at Chrome Frame also  https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a list (feel free to add to it):

- http://whatbrowser.org/
- http://browsehappy.com/

Comment: Both are good ones, but I wonder if WhatBrowser ever suggests to upgrade the one that I'm using? Because currently it only offers me to switch. Besides, does the site look the same in IE6 for example?

Comment: @mojuba if you set your user-agent to IE6 or another old browser, both sites will tell you that your browser is out of date and that you should upgrade.

Comment: @mojuba if you're not satisfied with those websites, then code your own CSS rules for every browser and every version and display custom messages telling your visitors to upgrade or switch to whatever browser you plan to support.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should require IE9+ and the latest version of all other browsers. You're going to be rejecting an awful lot of potential visitors. Can your website really not handle IE8, or Firefox 15? What you really want to do is redirect visitors with ancient browsers which isn't too many IE6 maybe IE7 right?

So your best bet is to have a FAQ or support site. Desk.com offers 1 free seat it's a great web app which you can setup a cname to such as http://support.yourdomain.com then have a FAQ similar to the one on the website you posted about upgrading your browser and how your site doesn't support old browsers. This way the visitor never leaves your domain and you can at least keep engaging them with your content as long as possible. It's easy enough to link to the latest browser download pages. Why not do it from your own domain?

Comment: The decision to dump earlier IE's was made based on statistics. Of course you can always write web sites that go as far as to support Netscape 3.0, the question is the price you are paying for maintaining the code. Turns out it is so incredibly cheap to write for the latest browsers, that you can ignore, say 3% of users in return. (And in our case it's even less than that)

Comment: What I meant was if you planned to only support the very latest browsers you're ignoring a large portion of visitors. I'm not suggesting supporting old out dated browsers. But you should got back a few major releases.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by saying "you should"? How do you know that, without any information as to what I'm doing, what kind of users etc etc?

Comment: It sounded as if you planned to redirect every user other than IE9+  which is just ridiculous IMO for any app any website. I would keep as many visitors on my site as possible along with making it as cross browser compliant as I could.